# Merge multiple views in an uiview

Tags: ios, uiimageview

In my app I've to take a picture and add the following information over the pic, these information are:

- Weather forecast
- Temperature
- GPS location

Until now I obtained these information by using GPS and a web service for weather forecast (open weather map). I made so:

1. I take the picture with the standard UIImagePicker
2. I put a button on my interface to show the picture to the user

When the user press the button the app open a new ViewController in which I show the picture just take and I added 2 UILabel (one for temperature and one for the location) and a UIImageView (to show an icon about the weather forecast). The UILabels and the UIImageView I draw directly on the StoryBoard.
Now I need to merge the picture with the 2 UILabel and with the UIImageView, there's a way to merge them in a single UIImageView?
I've to do that to save the picture with the weather forecast and location

**UPDATE**

I create a button to save the picture with the labels and the imageview and the code I wrote it's this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonSavePicture:(UIButton *)sender {
[self.imageView addSubview:self.labelPlace];
[self.imageView addSubview:self.labelTemperature];
[self.imageView addSubview:self.imageViewWeather];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageView.bounds.size);
[self.imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.filename];

[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(finalImage, 1) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

}

But when I go to see in the Documents directory if I saved correctly the picture I don't find it.

Comment: Change `NSDocumentationDirectory` to `NSDocumentDirectory`

Comment: Thank you! Now it's working! Just a question when I do this operation why the UILabel and the UIImageView moves a bit down?

Comment: May be due to view mode, I am not sure though. I think you can play with the context size you are creating.

Comment: No problem phonic: the manager says that the picture it's ok as I do, so thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can easily do it by capturing them. Follow steps.

1. Create a small parent view in storyboard put all controls you want to capture together inside. Create an outlet say `captureView`.
2. Call the following function when you need.

   ```
   -(void)capture{

         UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.captureView.bounds.size);
         [self.captureView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
         UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
         UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

         //FINAL OUTPUT
         self.imageView.image=capturedImage;
   }
   ```

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I updated the question to show you my code. I hope you can help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you using iOS7 have a look at the snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates: and the drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates: this one is used to include or capture subviews like labels etc. this will return a single UIView of everything on screen, then save that as a UIImage.

```
CGSize imgSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imgSize, NO , 0.0f);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *weatherImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(weatherImage, nil, nil, nil; //save to saved image album
```

If all went right you should have your "screenshot" in the photo album

Comment: I tried this solution, but I don't want to save a screenshot... If I save the screenshot I get too the button and the top bar and I want to have only the picture...